# How to Place Text Outside and to the Left of a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to achieve the following output in LaTeX:

- Place a `\tcolorbox` with a width of 10cm and a border thickness of 1pt in the center of a line.
- Place a ★ to the left of the `\tcolorbox`.

Specifically, I would like it to look like the image shown below. <s>In the image, the text inside the box is a single line, but I would like it to work with multiple lines as well.</s> (<s>This image has been pseudorandomly recreated using `\framebox`</s> [edit]I have replaced the image with a two-line text inside the box. )

If there is a way to solve this issue without using `\tcolorbox`, I would appreciate it if you could provide that method.

Your assistance in achieving this is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as starting point. Fine tuning and text in box I left to you.

Using `tcolorbox` a possible way to desired box and its placement can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{width=10cm,
        nobeforeafter,
        box align=center
        }


\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \[%begin{center}
(\star)\quad \begin{tcolorbox}Hello\\ World!\end{tcolorbox}
    \]%end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text block area)

For different box position, used `\documentclass` etc. you need to provide more information in your question.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful.

Comment: @Satoko, you are welcome!